# How to validate an exipred password in AD

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I understand how to validate a pwd and how to check if a pwd is expired but in my code I am automatically sending a user to a password reset page if their pwd is exired but I do not want to do this unless they are entering the correct password.

ValidateCredentials will return a false if the password is expired regardless of whether the password is correct or not. How can I tell the difference?

Comment: Which version of Windows Server is the server that is validating the credentials? 2003?

Comment: Do you have access to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace or does this need to be done in `System.DirectoryServices` only?